# The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled. Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

Why `List()` constructor is not accessible after Dart's null safety?

```dart
// Compile time error: 'List' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.
// The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled. 
// Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'.
List<int> foo = List();
```

However, you can still do:

```dart
List<int> foo = []; // No error
```

So, what's the difference between the two? Either both of them should show the error or none of them.

Comment: @Estradiaz That's not true, `List()` is also growable provided that you're not explicitly giving it a length.

Comment: @Estradiaz When I say `List<int>`, I am telling compiler that both `List` and any element it may contain must be non-nullable. In first case, I am simply creating an empty list and doing the same thing in second cast, one is not allowed but the other one is. That's the question.

Comment: You can read about the reasons for removing the `List()` constructor in this language issue which discuss the change: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/746

Comment: This is also explained in the [Understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#no-unnamed-list-constructor) article.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Instead of the pre-null-safety operations

```
var foo = List<int>();  // Now error
var bar = List<int>(n); // Now error
var baz = List<int>(0); // Now error
```

use the following:

```dart
var foo = <int>[];           // Always the recommended way.
var bar = List.filled(1, 0); // Not filled with `null`s.
var baz = List<int>.empty();
```

#### Long answer:

The `List` constructor had two uses:

- `new List()` to create an empty growable list, equivalent to `[]`.
- `new List(n)` to create a fixed-length list of length `n` filled with `null` values

With null safety, the second use was unsound most of the time, and there was no good way to fix it. It's possible to force a type argument to be non-nullable, but `List<T>(4)` only works when `T` is *nullable*. There is no way to enforce that.

So, the `List(n)` mode needed to go (replaced by `List.filled(n, value)` which forces you to provide a fill-value).
That left `List()`, which doesn't really carry its own weight. You can just use `[]` instead (and you [*should*](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-collection-literals-when-possible)!), so it was decided to remove the constructor entirely - all uses of it was either unsafe or useless.
(Also, it was a weird constructor already, because if we wanted to properly make it null safe, it would have an optional parameter with a non-nullable type and no default value.)

By removing it completely, it makes it possible to, potentially, introduce a new `List` constructor in the future, perhaps as a shorter alias for `List.filled`. One can hope.

Comment: I wish the same thing was mentioned in the official docs. Your answer is much more clear than someone who wrote the article of [Understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#no-unnamed-list-constructor) describing why `List()` is removed.

Comment: That article does a very good job of describing *what* we do, and the primary reason *why*, but it would be overkill to go into all the details. The article is full of information, and avoiding overloading the reader is also important. If you take *one* thing away from that section, it should be "`List` constructor is no more", and that's all we can hope for. (Also, the recommendation to use `[]` instead of `List()` isn't new, https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-collection-literals-when-possible, so the author probably didn't think it needed repeating.)

Comment: The [`List.empty({bool growable = false})`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-core/List/List.empty.html) constructor is also worth a mention. I landed here after some confusion around if the `[]` syntax creates a growable list (which it does, unless you are using the const empty list `const []`, which of course makes perfect sense but I had not thought through.)

Comment: Agree. The `List.empty` constructor is only needed for creating an empty non-growable or potentially non-growable list. For a growable list, you should just use a list literal.

Comment: @lrn quoting your `if we wanted to make it ... no default value` -- What was wrong in `List<T>()`. To make, say `List<int>()` null safe, we don't need optional parameter. It's just equivalent to `<int>[]`

Comment: There would be no technical problem in allowing `List()` in null safe code, you can create an empty list of any type (that's what `List.empty` does).
It was just much easier to restrict access to the `List` constructor entirely, instead of disallowing access when called with an argument. If you tear off the constructor (you can now, even if you couldn't then) then the type of the runtime type of that function would be `List<T> Function<T>([T?])`. It would not be safe to use in null-safe code.
Also, there is no loss of expressiveness since you still can, and always should, use `[]` instead.

Comment: @lrn Thanks so much for the explanation. I am really grateful to see you clearing every single doubt we (any SO user) may have.

Comment: forbiding `List()` is inconvinent when using `typedef XX = List<T>;`

Comment: how to make this work for nested lists?

Answer (score 10):

Apart from what [@lrn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63458217/12483095) sir mentioned, you can also create a list using:

```dart
List<int> foo = List<int>.empty(growable: true); // []
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because the the default **List()** element was deprecated how about you try using List.filled() element as shown below

```
void display() {
    var fixedList = new List<int>.filled(5, 0, growable: false);
    fixedList[0] = 0;
    fixedList[1] = 10;
    fixedList[2] = 20;
    fixedList[3] = 30;
    fixedList[4] = 40;
    print('Elements in the list are as follows: $fixedList');
  }
}
```

While for the Growable Length List you can try doing as shown below:

```
void main() {
    var growableList = new List<int>.filled(0,0, growable:true);
    growableList = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90];
    print('The elements in the growable list include: $growableList');
  }
```

Comment: Hi, "This is because the the default List() element was deprecated" -- which is why I wrote the question and for "how about you try using List.filled()", this is already provided by Lrn.

Comment: Suppose it's a list of objects  e.g`List<OnDemandVideo>`

Answer (score 0):

`_items = List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>();` can be written in null safty as

```
_items = List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>.from(<DropdownMenuItem<String>>[]);
```