# Flutter: List is deprecated?

Tags: flutter, dart

After upgrading to the latest version of flutter, I get a deprecation warning for all my Lists.

```
List<MyClass> _files = List<MyClass>(); =>'List' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.
```

Unfortunately, it does not give a hint of what to replace it with.
So what are we supposed to use instead now?

- Dart SDK version: **2.12.0-141.0.dev**
- Flutter: **Channel master, 1.25.0-9.0.pre.42**

Comment: see [list](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.html)

Comment: The lint means that the unnamed `List` *constructor* is deprecated, not the `List` type itself.

Comment: This question here and its answers are much more clear than the other one there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451506/the-default-list-constructor-isnt-available-when-null-safety-is-enabled-try

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Ok, found it, it's just how to instantiate it:

```
List<MyClass> _files = [];
```

**Edit**: maybe the most common ones, a bit more detailed according to the [docs](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html):

Fixed-length list of size 0:

```
List<MyClass> _list = List<MyClass>.empty();
```

Growable list:

```
List<MyClass> _list = [];
//or
List<MyClass> _list = List<MyClass>.empty(growable: true);
```

Fixed length with predefined fill:

```
int length = 3;
String fill = "test";
List<String> _list =  List<String>.filled(length, fill, growable: true);
// => ["test", "test", "test"]
```

List with generate function:

```
int length = 3;
MyClass myFun(int idx) => MyClass(id: idx);
List<MyClass> _list = List.generate(length, myFun, growable: true); 
// => [Instance of 'MyClass', Instance of 'MyClass', Instance of 'MyClass']
```

Comment: How do you initiate a list with static size like this?
(It is giving the same deprecation warning)

Comment: @spydon See edits

Answer (score 26):

```
List<MyClass> myList = <MyClass>[];
```

Answer (score 9):

From:

```
_todoList = new List();
```

Change to:

```
_todoList = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

old version

```
 List<Widget> widgetList = new List<Widget>();
```

new version

```
List<Widget> widgetList = [];
```