# How to use a List as member variable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I tried to define a class, which contains a List of a specific item-object, which will be populated within Constructor and will also receive new items at a later time:

```
class Repository {

  final List<Voting> _items = List<Voting>();

  Repository() {
    _items.add(Voting(1, "xyz", 0));
  }

  List<Voting> fetchItems() {
    return _items;
  }

}
```

However, Flutter is complaining:

> The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is
> enabled.

How to do?

Comment: Change the line ``final List<Voting> _items = List<Voting>();`` to ``List<Voting> _items = new List<Voting>();`` or ``List<Voting> _items = [];``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why List() constructor is not accessible in Dart's null safety?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451506/why-list-constructor-is-not-accessible-in-darts-null-safety)

Comment: use `final List<Voting> _items = [];` to define an empty list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
final List<Voting> _items = <Voting>[];
```

instead of

```
final List<Voting> _items = List<Voting>();
```

Answer (score 0):

`List()` is deprecated with Dart null safety, you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63458217/12483095).

You should either use `[]` or `List.filled` to create a list. For example:

```dart
final List<int> items = [];
final items = <int>[];
```

or

```dart
final List<int> items = List.filled(10, 0, growable: true)
```

Comment: Use an example of objects please not `int`

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris Replace `int` with the type of your object.

Comment: What of the params, where I see ```(10, 0, growable: true)``` , what should be placed there, because it complains that they are for int.

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris You should obviously be using the type of your object. I don't know what type it is. But you can create some mock data.