# Flutter: List deprecated?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, error-handling

when i want to use List constructor I get an error like this

checkList = List<.Check>();

"The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled. "
What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please try always to search first before asking a questoin as this one was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451506/why-list-constructor-is-not-accessible-after-darts-null-safety).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why List() constructor is not accessible after Dart's null safety?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451506/why-list-constructor-is-not-accessible-after-darts-null-safety)