# error: The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled

Tags: list, flutter, constructor, dart-null-safety

I getting this error, I don't get what a can do now, I am trying to import   videos from a youtube channel ...
[image]

[image]

Comment: use `[]` instead, or just `List.empty()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled. Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451506/the-default-list-constructor-isnt-available-when-null-safety-is-enabled-try)

Comment: Thank you, I used List.empty(growable: true); now it works ;)