# Error when create list of offset with value in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Create a list in my code of offset but show me an error with the below code

```
final List<Offset> p = List<Offset>(6);
```

Error:

```
The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled. (Documentation)
Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'.
```

But I can't convert it into literal with the (6) value because I have no knowledge of this!

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.generate.html

Answer (score 1):

This type of initialization has become invalid because `dart` now supports `null-safety`.

##### Change the initialization to:

```
final List<Offset> p = List.filled(6, <Your Initial Offset Value Here>)
```

###### Example :

```
final List<Offset> p = List.filled(6, const Offset(0, 0));
```

---

##### Extra: You can even try the below code if you want empty list.

```
List<Offset> p = List<Offset>.empty(growable: true); // []
```

---

##### Further Reference:

- [The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled. Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451506/the-default-list-constructor-isnt-available-when-null-safety-is-enabled-try)
- https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/746

Comment: <Your Initial Offset Value Here> how to declare here value, I really don't know

Comment: The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Offset'. (Documentation)